# Android app crashes after update and Open on Google Play

Tags: android, race-condition, onresume

I have an app on Google Play that tends to make the app crash if it is in the background when the app is updated and then re-opened by the user. The crash only happens sometimes, which is hinting towards a race condition somewhere. I am having a hard time debugging this and have only been able to reproduce this a few times myself, though I have got some stack traces reported by users. The stack traces are never pointing to the same line in the code, but the stack trace always enters my code through `performResumeActivity()` in Android and thus `onResume()` in my code. Note that this has never occurred to me or been reported by users in any other context than when updating the app (as far as I am able to tell). This does not mean that it only occurs when updating the app, but this is the only way I have seen the crash occur.

Steps to (sometimes) reproduce:

1. Install an old app version, e.g. by `adb install app-release-previous-version.apk`.
2. Open the app, play around a little bit and then minimize the app.
3. Open Google Play and update the app to the latest version.
4. Open the app from Google Play (we can open it from there after update).
5. The app crashes in `performResumeActivity()`/`onResume()` from time to time.

I'll add the code for the Activity where the crash occurs. Non-important code for this crash is not pasted, but let me know if I should add more code. The various stack traces I have are pasted at the end of the question.

**MyActivity (important parts only)**

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private MyMainFragment          myMainFragment          = null;
    private FilteredRecipes         myFilteredRecipes       = null;
    private MyShoppingList          myShoppingList          = null;
    private boolean mShouldReadAutomaticSave = false;

    // <snip> other members

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mShouldReadAutomaticSave = savedInstanceState == null;
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

        // Setup Toolbar / ActionBar.
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_main_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.my_navigationview);
        if (navigationView != null)
        {
            // <snip> Setup navigationView
        }

        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_drawer_layout);
        if (drawerLayout != null)
        {
           // <snip> Setup DrawerLayout
        }

        if (myShoppingList == null)     { myShoppingList    =   new MyShoppingList(this);       }
        if (myFilteredRecipes == null)  { myFilteredRecipes =   new MyFilteredRecipes(this);    }
        if (myMainFragment == null)     { myMainFragment    =   new MyMainFragment();           }

        if (savedInstanceState == null)
        {
            // Runs a thread to read recipes from an SQLite database. This is not the culprit.
            filterAllRecipes(null);
        }
        else
        {
            restoreState(savedInstanceState); // See method below
        }

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.none)
            .replace(R.id.my_content_frame, myMainFragment, "main_fragment")
            .commit();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        if (myFilteredRecipes != null)
        {
            myFilteredRecipes.onSaveInstanceState(outState); // Restores from Bundle
        }
        if (myShoppingList != null)
        {
            myShoppingList.onSaveInstanceState(outState); // Restores from Bundle
        }
        if (myMainFragment != null)
        {
            getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "myFragment", myMainFragment); // Restores from Bundle
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private void restoreState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        myShoppingList.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        myFilteredRecipes.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        myMainFragment = (MyMainFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "myFragment");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        // These tests were added as an attempt to cure the crash.
        // Probably fixed some of the crashes (stack traces below), but not the entire issue.
        if (myShoppingList == null) { myShoppingList = new MyShoppingList(this); }
        if (myFilteredRecipes == null) { myFilteredRecipes = new MyFilteredRecipes(this); }
        if (myMainFragment == null)
        {
            myMainFragment = new MyMainFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.none)
                .replace(R.id.my_content_frame, myMainFragment, "main_fragment")
                .commit();
        }

        if (mShouldReadAutomaticSave) // Set in onCreate() when applicable
        {
            mShouldReadAutomaticSave = false;
            final MyActivity mThis = this;
            Thread loadAutomaticSaveThread = new Thread()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    // Load automatic save if any. Must be done last to avoid race condition in LoadShoppingListTaks.
                    JSONObject automaticSave = ShoppingListFileHandler.readAutomaticSavedShoppingList(mThis);
                    if (automaticSave != null)
                    {
                        // This task takes the JSON data from the file read above, reads data from an SQLite database and sets up the myShoppingList data.
                        // Calls back to MyActivity.onShoppingListLoaded() when done.
                        // NOTE: There has been a crash in here when myShoppingList was null. This was before the "== null" tests above was added.
                        new ShoppingListFileHandler.LoadShoppingListTask(mThis, myShoppingList, automaticSave, false).execute();
                    }

                }
            };
            loadAutomaticSaveThread.setName("LoadAutomaticSaveThread");
            loadAutomaticSaveThread.start();
        }
    }

    // This is called from the LoadShoppingListTask when done.
    @Override
    public synchronized void onShoppingListLoaded()
    {
        if (myShoppingList != null)
        {
            // MyShoppingList.notifyDataSetChanged will call notifyDataSetChanged on a
            // RecyclerView adapter in the main Fragment. There is a stack trace for this below.
            myShoppingList.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

So that's the Activity where the crashes occur. Here are the stack traces I have got, some of them are partly obfuscated, since I hadn't understood what it did at that time.

**Stack trace for a missing Fragment**

Notes: It seems that we get a Fragment that is null, i.e. it is probably `myMainFragment` that is null when trying to restart the Activity.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.my.app/com.my.app.activities.MyActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0f0089 (com.my.app/my_content_frame) for fragment a{215e6dc #0 id=0x7f0f0089 main_fragment}
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3403)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3434)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2772)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0f0089 (com.my.app/my_content_frame) for fragment a{215e6dc #0 id=0x7f0f0089 main_fragment}
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1098)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1286)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1671)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:512)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostResume(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6430)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3392)
    ... 11 more
```

**Stack trace for Shopping List == null**

Notes: Crash in the `LoadShoppingListTask` since the `myShoppingList` member was null in the task. This happened before adding the tests in the start of `onResume()`.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String[] com.my.app.shoppinglist.j.a(android.content.Context, java.util.ArrayList, java.lang.String, android.util.SparseIntArray, org.json.JSONArray, java.util.ArrayList, boolean)' on a null object reference
    at com.my.app.filehandling.ShoppingListFileHandler$LoadShoppingListTask.doInBackground(ShoppingListFileHandler.java:882)
    at com.my.app.filehandling.ShoppingListFileHandler$LoadShoppingListTask.doInBackground(ShoppingListFileHandler.java:770)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    ... 4 more
```

**Stack trace from RecyclerView in the main Fragment**

Notes: There are multiple of these in various places in the RecyclerView when binding data. This particular RecyclerView lives in the main Fragment in the Activity. These crashes are the only times I have had problems with it. The RecyclerView reads its data from the `myShoppingList` member in the Activity. It seems like the Views are not created yet.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.widget.TextView com.my.app.gui.fragments.shoppinglist.k.a' on a null object reference
    at com.my.app.gui.fragments.shoppinglist.ShoppingListAdapter.bindRecipeName(ShoppingListAdapter.java:401)
    at com.my.app.gui.fragments.shoppinglist.ShoppingListAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ShoppingListAdapter.java:249)
    at com.my.app.gui.fragments.shoppinglist.ShoppingListAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ShoppingListAdapter.java:31)
    at com.my.app.gui.fragments.shoppinglist.ShoppingListAdapter.access$000(ShoppingListAdapter.java:31)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5471)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5504)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4741)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1994)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1390)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353)
<snip> Long stack trace inside Android classes...
```

**Stack trace with Fragment == null**

Notes: This was the first stack trace I got. Unfortunately I had not realized that I had to add deobscufation files at this point, so the stack trace is not that useful. But it seems obvious that the member `myMainFragment` was null at the crash.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.my.app/com.my.app.activities.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.my.app.gui.fragments.c.a.L()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3403)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3434)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2772)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.my.app.gui.fragments.c.a.L()' on a null object reference
    at com.my.app.activities.MyActivity.t(Unknown Source)
    at com.my.app.activities.MyActivity.onResume(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1255)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6412)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3392)
    ... 11 more
```

I cannot see where I have taken the wrong turn. Any hints and comments are appreciated.

Comment: You might also want to check if you use any database that might need migration?

Comment: @Polarbear0106: So how do you suggest I troubleshoot this? It is not easy to attach to the app process before it crashes, so I am left with looking at the stack traces and trying to deduce the cause of issues from them. And I have stared at the stack traces, but not been able to find the root cause, hence this question.

Comment: @Eenvincible: The database schemes are identical for both the versions. I am confident that it has nothing to do with the SQLite database in the app.

Comment: Look in the initialization where myMainFragment and Shopping List would be initialized. Also check what happens when everything shuts down. If you pause the thread and do not completly shut down, and you null some things are those things reinitialized when the app restarts?

Comment: Does it crash right after it opens?

Comment: All initialization works fine for a given installation of the app at both start and restart. If I install the latest version of the app on a device or in an emulator, all variables are initialized and set up properly when minimizing and re-opening the app. Killing the app with `adb` while it is in the background and re-opening the app also works as expected. All variables are set up properly. The only times I see these errors are when the app is upgraded and then re-opened - I have not been able to reproduce this locally without an upgrade from Google Play.

Comment: Yes, it crashes straight after opening after upgrading the app from Google Play. The app may also have been updated in the background if the settings allow it. Then the crash also occurs instantly if it occurs at all.

Comment: Has it always been like that or did it change after some version?

Comment: I am not really sure since the crash only occurs sometimes and the user base is still very small (~100). It was around 50 when the crash was first reported. So it might have been there all along, but it is hard to tell. I'll do some more digging and regression testing for the versions where it was first reported.

Comment: I found this post after one of our team observed that our app seems to have a lot of odd behavior after an upgrade. If he installs an older version, opens it and then does an upgrade to the newest -- he can trigger instability which can't be triggered before the upgrade or after the phone is rebooted.

We are investigating and will report back. But it almost sounds like some of the old code is still running as background processes mixed in with the new code.

Comment: same issue happening with my app.. classnotfound exception for the class which was present in previous version but not in new version. thr is no reference of that class in complete project still it give exception